# Triangle UIView - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, ios8

So I'm making a game in which I am dropping objects which have to be destroyed by a spike(triangle) at the bottom of the screen by a user.

I cannot work out how to make a UIView that is a triangle. However I have been able to make it work as a rectangle like this:

```
 let barrier = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:125, y: 650, width: 130, height:20))
 barrier.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
 view.addSubview(barrier)
```

And this has worked. But I cannot work out how to make a triangle. The reason I want it as a UIView is because im using collisions on it and for the user to move it. I have tried a PNG triangle but it detects the collision as the border of the image not the start of the triangle.

I have tried this but it doesn't work...

```
 let square = UIView(frame: CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 50, 0), CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 100, 50), CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, 100))
 square.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
 view.addSubview(square)
```

Any and all help will be appreciated,

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Add a CAShapeLayer to your view, and give it a triangular path (which you create using a UIBezierPath).

Comment: It sounds like you're using UIKit for a purpose more suited to SpriteKit

Answer (score 110, accepted):

**Updated for *Swift 3*:**

```
class TriangleView : UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.maxX / 2.0), y: rect.minY))
        context.closePath()

        context.setFillColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.60)
        context.fillPath()
    }
}
```

---

***Swift 2*:**

```
import UIKit

class TriangleView : UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        var ctx : CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextBeginPath(ctx)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect))
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect))
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, (CGRectGetMaxX(rect)/2.0), CGRectGetMinY(rect))
        CGContextClosePath(ctx)

        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.60);
        CGContextFillPath(ctx);
       }
 }
```

This will start from MinX, MaxY;
Draw a line from the start to MaxX, MaxY;
Draw a line from MaxX,MaxY to MaxX/2, MinY;
Then close the path to the start location.

The next part sets the color you want to use. In this example 255,127,0, Alpha 0.6
Then will fill the path you just drew above with the set color.

Then in your View Controller

***Swift 3*:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let triangle = TriangleView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 25 , height: 30))
        triangle.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(triangle)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

---

***Swift 2*:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let triangle = TriangleView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 20, 25, 30))
        triangle.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
        view.addSubview(triangle)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

However, this is going to cause the same problem as the frame of this view is still going to be a rectangle. UIKit works with rectangles, you would have to use another framework, like Sprite Kit.

Comment: Im getting Initializers may only be declared within a type on:

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

Comment: Did you create a class declaration?
`class TriangeView : UIView {
}`

Comment: I believe `triange` is a typo? :)

Comment: @Arefly Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: how can I change the **color** of the triangle dynamically?

Comment: @UdayNaidu
To change the color dynamically, add a property to `TriangleView` to hold the color and use that to set the fill color. Also check out "The View Drawing Cycle" in the documentation.

Comment: i wasnt trying to draw triangle. but that helped my to draw trapezoid :d

Comment: it would draw black background, we should add `self.isOpaque = false` to `init` to fix it

Answer (score 26):

> Swift 5:

This code worked for me for different sides. for `UIView` using `CGMutablePath()` and `CAShapeLayer()`

*Assuming your view's height and width are same.

*Set your views's background color as clearColor.

**A) Right Side**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var triangleView: UIView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setRightTriangle()   
    }

 func setRightTriangle(){
        let heightWidth = triangleView.frame.size.width //you can use triangleView.frame.size.height
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: heightWidth/2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:0))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        triangleView.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }
```

[image]

---

**B) Left Side**

```
 func setLeftTriangle(){
        let heightWidth = triangleView.frame.size.width
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: heightWidth/2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:0))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        triangleView.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }
```

[image]

---

**C) Up Side**

```
  func setUpTriangle(){
        let heightWidth = triangleView.frame.size.width
           let path = CGMutablePath()

           path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: heightWidth))
           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y: heightWidth/2))
           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth, y:heightWidth))
           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:heightWidth))

           let shape = CAShapeLayer()
           shape.path = path
           shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

           triangleView.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
       }
```

[image]

---

**D) Down Side**

```
  func setDownTriangle(){
        let heightWidth = triangleView.frame.size.width
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth, y:0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        triangleView.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }
```

[image]

*Change X any Y values according to your requirement.

Comment: If someone needs upsaide-triagleview from middle of the view, use this path. path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth, y:heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:heightWidth/2))

Answer (score 9):

CAShapeLayer it can change the shape of layers.

```
    var mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.frame = self.layer.bounds

    let width = self.layer.frame.size.width
    let height = self.layer.frame.size.height

    var path = CGPathCreateMutable()

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 30, 0)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width, 0)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width, height)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, height)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 30, 0)

    mask.path = path

    // CGPathRelease(path); - not needed

    self.layer.mask = mask

    var shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.frame = self.bounds
    shape.path = path
    shape.lineWidth = 3.0
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

    self.layer.insertSublayer(shape, atIndex: 0)
```

Answer (score 9):

I've modified the previous code a bit to add margin and fill color as inspectable and it works well with Swift4:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class TriangleView : UIView {
    var _color: UIColor! = UIColor.blue
    var _margin: CGFloat! = 0

    @IBInspectable var margin: Double {
        get { return Double(_margin)}
        set { _margin = CGFloat(newValue)}
    }


    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor? {
        get { return _color }
        set{ _color = newValue }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + _margin, y: rect.maxY - _margin))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - _margin, y: rect.maxY - _margin))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.maxX / 2.0), y: rect.minY + _margin))
        context.closePath()

        context.setFillColor(_color.cgColor)
        context.fillPath()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried a PNG triangle but it detects the collision as the border of the image not the start of the triangle.

There is nothing you can do about that if you're going to use simple-minded collisions (e.g. the built-in UIKit Dynamics - it does *only* rectangular view collisions). If you want advanced shape collisions, either you must implement them yourself or you must use Sprites.

> and for the user to move it

That is much easier to deal with: simply override `hitTest` for this view and return `nil` if the place the user touches is outside the borders of the triangle image.

Comment: For how to do hit testing for drawn shapes, see the discussion in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_hit_testing_for_drawings

Answer (score 0):

This will give you either a **shorter** point or a **longer** point in either of the 4 directions. Easy to use:

1 -create a class (c+p):

```
import UIKit

class PointingTriangleView: UIView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
    
    var fillColorCGColor = UIColor.brown.cgColor
    
    var pointingLongDown = false
    var pointingShortDown = false

    var pointingLongUp = false        
    var pointingShortUp = false
    
    var pointingLongLeft = false
    var pointingShortLeft = false
    
    var pointingLongRight = false
    var pointingShortRight = false
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        context.beginPath()
        
        if pointingLongDown {
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY))
        }
        
        if pointingShortDown {
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY))
        }
        
        if pointingLongUp {
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
        }
        
        if pointingShortUp {
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
        }
        
        if pointingLongLeft {
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        }
        
        if pointingShortLeft {
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        }
        
        if pointingLongRight {
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        }
        
        if pointingShortRight {
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        }
        
        context.closePath()
        
        context.setFillColor(fillColorCGColor)
        context.fillPath()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

2 -create an object, make sure to **set the direction** and color that you prefer:

```
lazy var pointingArrow: PointingTriangleView = {
    let v = PointingTriangleView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    v.pointingShortUp = true // *** set the direction that you prefer here ***

    v.fillColorCGColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor // select your preferred color and make sure it ends in .cgColor 
    return v
}()
```

3 -set the `Anchors`:

```
view.addSubview(pointingArrow)

pointingArrow.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true 
pointingArrow.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
pointingArrow.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
pointingArrow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
struct Triangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 200.0, y: 40.0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 40.0, y: 40.0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 120.0, y: 200.0))
        
        path.closeSubpath()
        
        
        
        return path
    }
    
}
```