# Access the UIBezierPath drawn on a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath

I have drawn a custom shaped `UIView` where I overwrote the `drawRect(_:)` method to be a triangle using this answer: [The Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650343/triangle-uiview-swift/)

Now I want to highlight that triangle when the user taps it. I suppose I could draw another triangle on top of it with a different color, but I want this view to perform other tasks later. The custom view's bounds overlaps another view, so I can't just change the whole `UIView's` background color, only the `UIBezierPath's` background color. If you look at the attached image, the selected view's background is covering the nearby view. How can I access just the `UIBezierPath's` layer and change it's color?

[The overlapping background is the top right view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37kPX.png)

Comment: i dont find any triangle in the image :P

Comment: Mr. T I got excited and drew a more complex shape :)

Comment: are all the drawings are donw with one bezier path or multiple bezier paths ?

Comment: There's two non-rectangle view's in that image, directly "across the street" from each other. Those are separate UIView files that are added on top of the main view which contains all the standard rectangle views. The non-rectangle views are drawn in the method I described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the view a tap gesture recognizer. Now you know when it is tapped. You can use hit-testing and your knowledge of the shape to know whether the tap is within the triangle.

> How can I access just the UIBezierPath's layer and change it's color?

If you had used the CAShapeLayer approach, you could have done that; all you would have to do is change the layer's `fillColor` (if that is what highlighting means to you).

But since you elected to use `drawRect:`, there is no "UIBezierPath's layer". You will have to call `setNeedsDisplay`, thus causing `drawRect:` to be called again — and this time, you draw the triangle filled (or whatever highlighting means to you).

Comment: The View has a tap gesture recognizer right now. Can you direct me to somewhere I can read about the CAShapeLayer? Seems like I should go ahead and do that.

Comment: The question you already linked to has answers that talk about it.

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with using `drawRect:`. I do this all the time. You simply have to maintain some sort of state: where is the path, is it filled or not, etc. That way, when you draw, you do all the right things for that moment. And you can maintain multiple paths, of course.

Comment: Thanks. Let me mess with it for a minute and if it works I'll mark you correct. Looks initially like it'll do what I need.

Comment: The layer is drawing properly, just like with the `UIBezierPath` but now I can't access the layer in the `UIView` where i'm placing the shape as a subview. How would I access the view to change it's layer's color?

Comment: @sl0anage If a new question arises, ask a new question! That way you can show in detail what you're currently doing. If you do, put a link to it in a comment here so I can take a look and see if I can help.