# How can I make a triangular UIView?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uikit

I'm new to Swift.  I have a regular rectangular UIView in my app, I am trying to make it triangular so that the user can draw within the bounds.

Any suggestions?  I'm using UIKit and would like to avoid SpriteKit.

Thank you!

Comment: Use UIBezierPath.

Comment: The same question is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650343/triangle-uiview-swift

Answer (score 0):

[Result triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSqFn.png)

Code in swift5

```
//TriangleView

extension UIView {

    func setRightTriangle(targetView:UIView?){
        let heightWidth = targetView!.frame.size.width //you can use triangleView.frame.size.height
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: heightWidth/2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:0))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        targetView!.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }

    func setLeftTriangle(targetView:UIView?){
        let heightWidth = targetView!.frame.size.width
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: heightWidth/2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:0))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        targetView!.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }

    func setUpTriangle(targetView:UIView?){
     let heightWidth = targetView!.frame.size.width
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth, y:heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:heightWidth))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        targetView!.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }

    func setDownTriangle(targetView:UIView?){
        let heightWidth = targetView!.frame.size.width
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth, y:0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        targetView!.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }
}
```